# Find which Maven dependencies are downloaded from JCenter?

Tags: maven, jcenter

Since JCenter and Bintray are shutting down I'm trying to migrate away from them. During this process, I'm trying to find which dependencies are downloaded from JCenter and which are downloaded from Maven central.

So my question is simply, is there an easy way in Maven to check which dependencies are currently downloaded from JCenter and are not available in Maven Central?

It can be really cumbersome and time-consuming to figure this out manually if for large projects with lots of dependencies.

Comment: I would say turn off access to JCenter and build your project... I wouldn't expect that so many deps are not on Central...(Maybe I'm wrong)..

Comment: For this to work, I would need to remove my local maven repository, which I'm not very keen on doing (otherwise Maven will use my locally downloaded dependencies). Sure, I could just rename the original .m2 repo to something else temporarily. But hopefully, there's a better approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "I would need to remove my local maven repository," ? Easiest and fastest way to get things done...

Comment: I would also just rename the local repository, deactivate JCenter and see what happens.